# Image disappears when dropped outside our pictureboxes

Tags: c#, image, drag-and-drop, picturebox

First off, thanks for reading this and taking the time to try help us.
We are currently making this project for our c# class, we had to study Drag&Drop by ourselves but we are having a problem.

Situation:
We have 6 starting pictureboxes with images, we also have 6 textboxes with a description, the idea is simple, match them together. However, if we drag an image from the starting picturebox into one of the 6 answer pictureboxes but by accident drop it on the form, it disappears.

We are clueless to find a way to actually 'reset' the image back to starting position when not placed in a picturebox.

```
private void Picture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
            PictureBox source = (PictureBox)sender;
            naam = source.ImageLocation;
            source.DoDragDrop(source.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
            source.Image = null;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new RijException("Picturebox is momenteel leeg.");
            }
            catch (RijException)
            {

            }
        }


    }

    private void Picture_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
            PictureBox source = (PictureBox)sender;
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;


    }

    private void Picture_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
            PictureBox source = (PictureBox)sender;
            source.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            source.Tag = naam;
    }
```

So when we actually drop the image (while dragging) outside the picturebox (in the form) It will just disappear, What we need is a solution to reset it to starting position, but don't know how we could manage to pull that off.

Comment: Please consider meeting the guidelines laid out here, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, it would make it possible for those here to help you.

Comment: use mentioned link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1

Comment: It sounds like a pretty straight-forward and simple task. As the others said, please post code, so we may help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I hope this is enough code to actually describe our problem, Sorry for not following the guidelines correctly, my apologies.